# achievability of average

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, average

Out of a textbook.

Informally, the goal is to show that if from a given set of values ($2^n$ many values) in the range of $[0,m]$ (for fixed $m,k$), more than half are less than $m\cdot (1-\frac{1}{2^{k-1}})$, the average cannot be $m\cdot (1-\frac{1}{2^k})$.

The proof proceeds as follows:

let $\ell$ be the number of  values less than $m(1-2^{-k})$,

let $u = 2^n - \ell$ be the number of values greater or equal $m(1-2^{-k})$

then the expected average $E \leq \frac{1}{2^n}\cdot \ell \cdot[m\cdot(1-2^{-k+1})-1] + u\cdot m$

assuming $E = m\cdot(1-2^{-k})$ will yield

$m\cdot(1-2^{-k}) \leq \frac{1}{2^n}\cdot \ell \cdot[m\cdot(1-2^{-k+1})-1] + u\cdot m$

and thus

$2^n\cdot m\cdot(1-2^{-k}) \leq \ell \cdot[m\cdot(1-2^{-k+1})-1] + u\cdot m$

which, I quote, "can only be satisfied for $ u > \ell $ ".

End of proof.

That claim isn't quite as obvious to me as it apparently should be.
Why does it hold?

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing is a bit unnnecessarily complicated. Instead of introducing $k$, it would be more straightforward to say more generally that if more than half the values are less than $m(1-\rho)$ and none of the values are greater than $m$, then the average can't be $m\left(1-\frac\rho2\right)$. This perhaps becomes more obvious if you consider transforming the values according to $x\to \frac{m-x}m$: if more than half the values are greater than $\rho$ and none are negative, the average can't be $\frac\rho2$.

Applying these transformations to your proof as a whole will probably also make it easier to check the claim you quoted.